# How to replace a token only when it's used as a value not from attribute in html?

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

```
const app = document.getElementById("app");

const lessonText = `
<span style="font-family: &quot;Courier New&quot;, Courier, monospace;">
  <font color="#af88ff">&quot;,&quot;</font>
  <font color="#ff5a96">Nonstudents</font>
  <span>c(&quot;,&quot;)</span>
</span>
`;

const replacedText = lessonText.replace(/&quot;/g, '“');

app.innerHTML = replacedText;
```

How to replace all `&quot;` with `“` exept when `&quot;` is used as an attribute in tag.

Example,

1. `<span>c(&quot;,&quot;)</span>` - I want both `&quot;` to be
   replaced with `“`.
2. `<span style="font-family: &quot;Courier New&quot;">abcd</span>` - I don't want `&quot;` to be replaced
   because they're from attribute, style, not value.

Comment: You cannot meaningfully process HTML using a Regular Expression. What you're trying to do _might_ be impossible. Is there a reason you can't use a DOM parser instead?

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been obsolete for maybe 20 years or more

Comment: @Dai I would like to use DOMParser as well, how can I come up with a solution with DOM Parser?

Comment: Well with a DOM parser, you would go through the elements recursively, and only work on _text nodes_ to begin with.